# iOS mapKit refresh direction when the user's current location is updated

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, direction, mkoverlay

I am developing an application that allows the user to show the itinerary from the current location to the destination.
The itinerary must be refreshed when the user's current location changes.
I am using the LocationManager to detect the current location.
When the current location changes, i re-fetch the directions and display a new itinerary that starts from the new current location.
Is there a better and cleaner solution to achieve this ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is correct way. Use following method of `CLLocationManagerDelegate`

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{

}
```

to get location update and chage the display accordingly.

Comment: You mean that every time the current location gets updated, i need to get the directions again and refresh the itinerary. Correct ?